# JS expression to calculate and set an input value based on multiple variables from previous response output

Tags: javascript

Need guidance in forming a JS expression to calculate the below response variables and set a specific input value

**3 variables and its values are:**

1. AllocatedConsumption = 9
2. Availability = 1
3. Capacity = 10

I Want to add **AllocatedConsumption** + **Availability** so **capacity** is always marked as 10 ir-respective what the values are because values are changing dynamically ! Sometime Availability can be in - value

Comment: Does both AllocatedConsumption and Availability keeps on changing or only AllocatedConsumption?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me so quickly. Sometime yes both AllocatedConsumption and Availability will be changing and sometimes it remains 0(constant) so capacity is unchanged !

Comment: So Allocated Consumption + Availability must always be equal to 10 whether let's assume Allocated Consumption = 1 and Availability = 2

Comment: Expression be like => allocatedConsumption + availability + (10 - (allocatedConsumption+availability)) = Capacity

Up vote if it's solves your query

Comment: Anupum Thanks ! I am a beginner. Can u help with a sample code for the above solution please ?

Comment: Sure I will post it in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let allocatedConsumption;
let availability;
let capacity; 
capacity = allocatedConsumption + availability + (10 - (allocatedConsumption + availability))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks Anupum! It worked. I did vote, but since i am a new contributor, its not showing as 1

Comment: @ANUPAMCHAUDHARY if my variable values are coming dynamically from another call, how can i represent my variables in above case ? it not always 9, 1 & 10